# Observing DataTable RowChanged Event using Rx

Tags: c#

I need to observe on datatable RowChanged event and subscribe to it using ReactiveExtensions.

Let us say I have a datatable as below:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof (int)));
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
```

I need to observe on the RowChanged event and pass the observable to the clients of my class. Towards this I'm trying to hookup the RowChanged event via FromEventPattern, but it does not accept it. Code is as below:

```
var eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<DataRowChangeEventArgs>
((DataRowChangeEventHandler<DataRowChangeEventArgs> i) => table.RowChanged += i,
(DataRowChangeEventHandler<DataRowChangeEventArgs> i) => table.RowChanged -= i);
```

> It says : The non-generic type 'System.Data.DataRowChangeEventHandler'
>   cannot be used with type argument

How can I do this using Rx? Please note that I'm using .NET 3.5.

Thanks,
-Mike